# Determining how long a task sits in the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor's BlockingQueue

Tags: java

I'm using a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) and I suspect that there are at times too many outstanding requests for the number of threads available (yes...I probably need to tune the number of threads). More specifically I'd like to know how long tasks are sitting in the thread pool's BlockingQueue waiting for an available thread after the scheduled task has fired. Seems that I would need to have a hook into when the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor adds the task to its internal queue (`ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.super.queue.add(task)`) but looking at the JDK's API and code there doesn't seem to be an easy way.

Thoughts and/or suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Can you implement this behavior in your Task, to keep track of its own state?

Comment: +1: You can add a task periodically which knows when it was added if you don't modify existing ones.